# Сравнить элементы списков в заданном диапазоне

Tags: python

Есть списки А и Б. Как без цикла найти совпадения в заданном диапазоне `+-0.15`? Например, `А = ['50.25', '60.44']`, `Б = ['60.54', '70.0']`. Должен быть вывод: '60.44' и '60.54'. 
Списков очень много, поэтому цикл в цикле работает очень долго.

Comment: А добавьте код. Не очень понятно, что там у вас очень долго работает

Comment: А почему вы решили, что это можно сделать без цикла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно просто найти близкие значения во всех списках, то можно попробовать сделать так:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

a = ['50.25', '60.44']
b = ['60.54', '70.0']
c = ['18.43', '60.69']
threshold = 0.15

longlist = sorted(list(map(float,it.chain(a,b,c))))

deltas = np.ediff1d(longlist)
res = [(longlist[x], longlist[x+1]) for x in range(len(deltas)) if deltas[x]<=threshold]
print(res)
```

> [(60.44, 60.54), (60.54, 60.69)]

Comment: чуть более numpy-ый вариант: `np.sort(np.array(list(it.chain(a,b,c))).astype('float'))` ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Сортируем один из списков. Если они разные по длине, то сортируем длиннейший.
2. Итерируемся по второму списку. Для каждого элемента из второго списка ищем в первом (отсортированном) списке методом половинного деления пару соседних элементов, между которыми стоит значение текущего элемента.
3. Вычисляем для текущего элемента, цепляет ли он с диапазоном +-0.15 какой-либо из этой пары элементов. Если цепляет, то нужно проверять в этом направлении следующие элементы, пока не перестанет цеплять.
4. PROFIT!!!